# Puppy Linux hangs at Recognizing Optical Devices

Tags: linux, boot, usb, kernel-panic, puppylinux

I have been trying from many days to bring back the life to my old Pentium 4 machine having 1GB of RAM. But first when I boots it stucks here ( shown in the image)

[image: image1]

Then I decided to to run the live-USB based Puppy Linux, it normally boots from the USB but got stuck again, this time on "Recognizing optical devices ".

Next time when I booted I turned off SERR error generation from BIOS, but again, it stuck at the same point, only this time it shows some error which I am posting:

[image: image2]

I have tried many other OS but the same problem still persists. Please help me identify what is the cause of this problem.

Comment: What were the other OSs you tried?  BTW, if you aren't able to get a solution here, Puppy's own forum, http://murga-linux.com/puppy/, has a concentration of experts and is a good resource.

Comment: The 'Not tainted 3.14.55' jumps out at me. Googling it, along with "puppy" and "slacko" brought me to a possible solution... http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/puppy-71/puppy-hangs-on-start-up-4175575524/

Comment: Did you ever get this solved?  Can you update us on the status and solution?  If you did solve it, consider posting your own answer to help others with a similar problem.